# What is a good way to load and update many records without loading the entire set at once using AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, relational-database

I would like to load and process a bunch of records (1m+) one-by-one without loading the entire set at once in AWS.

Speciifcally, I am working on a system that matches users together.

1. A user submits an item rating
2. All ratings of the same item by other users are selected (1m+)
3. A record in another table is updated for every rating with the new relationship strength of the two users.

The two tables would look like this:

```
RATINGS: userID, itemID, rating

RELATIONSHIPS: userID1, userID2, relationshipStrength
```

I would like to process ratings without having to load the entire set at once (1m+). I would like to process each rating one-by-one, make the comparison, update the relationship and move on to the next. Data consistency and accuracy is not important - if a couple of relationships gets missed its fine.

What AWS tools would be good to achieve this?

I was looking into dynamodb + lamda but (I believe) this requires loading the whole set:

1. Save rating to dynamodb
2. Dynamodb triggers lambda
3. Lambda queries all other ratings from dynamodb (want to avoid this)
4. Loop through each rating and update relationship in another dynamodb table

I want to avoid having to load the entire set into memory in step 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only dealing with 1 million records, I would recommend writing a program to do this **in memory**, rather than continually querying a database. It would run much faster.

**Memory requirements** would only be a few bytes for each record (eg 6 bytes for Ratings table, 6 bytes for Relationships table, plus overhead). With 1 million ratings (~6MB) and, say, 10,000 users cross-referenced to 1000 users (~60MB) you can fit that in RAM.

If memory is a problem but you don't need to do this calculation very often, you could launch a **Memory Optimized EC2 instance** under Spot pricing and do it relatively cheaper.

Of course, if you intend to scale in future, you'll need a better way of doing this that doesn't need everything in memory, such as using an SQL database or distributing the work amongst multiple workers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The 1m+ isn't the total number of records in the system, but the number of ratings of a single item. So, for exmample, there may be a million items, each with a million ratings, from 10m users. I actually have a functional prototype that is in-memory, as you suggest, I am trying to move it to something more scalable.

Comment: If it turns out to be stupidly big, you could look at writing something in Amazon EMR (Hadoop). Or, if you can keep all the ratings in memory, just loop through each unique customer pair, streaming the results to disk. Good luck!